# Android: editText's underline (drawable?) stays highlighted after focus is switched

Tags: android, android-edittext

i am completely unexperienced in coding, BUT am fiddling around with a simple android app. 
I am using an editText, whose text is changed upon MotionEvent.ACTION_UP. Problem is, the underline will stay highlighted even after the focus has been cleared (i tried to force this with clearfocus().

Code:

```
binding.editText1fh.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
private int touchcount = 0;
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
        if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // <Do Something>
            binding.editText1fh.clearFocus();
            return true;}
        else return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the focus on MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, that's when user removes his finger. Also, try removing focus from the view class at the TODO

```
binding.editText1fh.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
private int touchcount = 0;
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
    if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

        binding.editText1fh.clearFocus();
        //TODO
        return true;}
    else if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // <Do Something>
        binding.editText1fh.clearFocus();
        return true;}
}
});
```

Comment: I thought MotionEvent.ACTION_UP corresponds to the finger being removed. I once used DOWN, but then the textField was filled when the finger was put onto the screen.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. I wrote without looking at the screen. Can you try interchanging the code. I'm updating the code, also.